# Full file not displaying on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I've recently added a project to GitHub and some of the files are not displaying fully.  For example - https://github.com/Fitzpasd/Simple-programming-language-incl.-Scanner---Parser/blob/master/SymTab.cs

If you click 'Raw' then the entire file shows up.  Is there an issue with my formatting perhaps?  I am using Git on windows and have all the recommended settings (file conversion etc).

Comment: Perhaps take it up with Github support directly?

Comment: Looks like a bug in github, probably related to their syntax highlighting library. I agree with Abizern: you should file a support ticket at github so they can investigate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you managed to do that, but when I download the "raw" version (no git at hand), its newlines follow the old mac convention. That is, it uses only the `CR` (`\r`) character (as opposed to `CR LF` as on Windows, or `LF` as on unix-ish systems). As that's rather obscure option these days (and depending on the programming language and libraries used, nontrivial to support), it may simply be unsupported. This assumption is supported by a [GitHub article on newlines](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings) not mentioning the `CR` convention at all and goes by "Mac == `LF`". Can't hurt to contact GitHub support though.

Other files which are displayed correctly don't have those (e.g. `Scanner.cs` uses the unix convention).